# Установка минимальных значений

Tags: android

Можно ли в гаджетах на время, устанавливать минимальные значения?
Например, что бы я не мог выставить время меньше текущего.
Или подскажите варианты решения, такой задачи =)

Answer (score 2):

Идея. Можно в обработчике OnTimeChangedListener класса TimePicker проверять значения времени, и если оно не удовлетворяют какому-нибудь правилу, выставлять их в нужное значение

```
timePicker = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.TimePicker);
timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(mTimePickerChangedListener);
```

и

```
private TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener mTimePickerChangedListener =
    new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {

    public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hour, int minute) {
        showUpdate(view, date, hour, minute);           
    }
};

private void showUpdate(TimePicker timePicker, Date date, int hour, int minute) { 
    // Выставить новое время

    timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(null);
    timePicker.setCurrentMinute(nextMinute);
    timePicker.setCurrentHour(nextHour);
    timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(mTimePickerChangedListener);
}
```